# avoid top padding inside a pre-wrap div

Tags: html, css

How to keep all css styles in the bellow example, but remove top pading - an entire line in height.

I tried:

```
 <div class="bwrap">lorem ipsum
```

instead of:

```
<div class="bwrap">
lorem ipsum
```

and it works, but I'm not happy with that solution, it affects readability of the code in code editor.

Any other solution?

```css
.bwrap{
  padding:0 14px;
  -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
  outline:none;
  letter-spacing:0.5px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="bwrap">
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amend
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a `<pre>` tag instead. It doesn't seem to mind having a new line at the start (but I've only tested it in Chrome):

```css
.bwrap{
  padding:0 14px;
  -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
  outline:none;
  letter-spacing:0.5px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background:gold;
  font: inherit;  
}
```

```html
<pre class="bwrap">
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amend
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the CSS this is not possible since `white-space: pre-wrap` does this:

1. Successive blanks are retained.
2. Lines are wrapped at

   - **line break characters in the source code**
   - `<br>`
   - at necessary places to fill the line.

So it`s only possible with the inline solution you already have - unfortunately

Comment: I hate this words - `it's not possible`. thanks a lot, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that every line will begin at a new line, then you can try the below solution using **[`::first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)** pseudo selector.

By setting `line-height:0` you can visually remove the empty line.

```css
.bwrap {
  padding: 0 14px;
  -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: gold;
}

.bwrap::first-line {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bwrap">
  lorem ipsum
  dolor sit 
  amend
</div>
```

Comment: it still has the padding on the top ^^

Comment: Good solution but it looks to be that the OP wants the text to be user-editable (`-moz-user-modify: read-write;`) which scuppers your first-line line-height hack. ;(

Comment: @DigitalJedi Can't see it on my machine, maybe some browser issue ?

Comment: @Moob I didn't notice it, well then this is not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The best solution may be to wrap it in an outer div and position the inner div relatively:

```css
.bwrap{
  padding:0 14px;
  -moz-user-modify: read-write;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
  outline:none;
  letter-spacing:0.5px;
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-pre-wrap;
  white-space:-o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}

.outer {
    background: gold;
    height: 3.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="bwrap">
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amend
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is user-modifiable so you can live-edit it. Unfortunately this means the user is able to delete and retype characters at the top (within that negative area)